# How to change the path of the folder while uploading images in custom form?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, custom

I have a custom form for uploading the images and it is working right.
But it saves the images in the `media` folder and I want to save the images under some other folder in the `media` folder.

Here is my save action in the controller

```
<?php
class Vertax_Blog_Adminhtml_ArticleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('blog/article')
            ->_addBreadcrumb('Article Manager','Article Manager');
   return $this;
 }
  public function indexAction()
  {
     $this->_initAction();
 $this->_title($this->__("Vertax_Article"));
     $this->renderLayout();
  }
  public function editAction()
  {
       $articleId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
       $articleModel = Mage::getModel('blog/article')->load($articleId); 
   $categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', $articleId);  
      if ($articleModel->getId() || $articleId == 0)
       {
         Mage::register('article_data', $articleModel);
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->_setActiveMenu('blog/article');
         $this->_addBreadcrumb('article Manager', 'article Manager');
         $this->_addBreadcrumb('Article Description', 'Article Description');
         $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
         $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('blog/adminhtml_article_edit'))
              ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('blog/adminhtml_article_edit_tabs'));
         $this->renderLayout();
       }
       else
       {
             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                   ->addError('Article does not exist');
             $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
   }
   public function newAction()
   {
      $this->_forward('edit');
   }
   public function saveAction()
   {
     if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
     {
       try {
             $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
     //echo "<pre>";print_r($postData); 
     $articleModel = Mage::getModel('blog/article');
     $imgFilename = NULL;


    if($_FILES['image']['name'] != '') 
      {
                try { 
                     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
         $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                     // Set media as the upload dir
                     //$media_path  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
         $media_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'blog' . DS;
                     $imgFilename = $media_path . $postData['image'];
                     // Upload the image

                     $uploader->save($media_path, $_FILES['image']['name']);
                    }
                 catch (Exception $e) 
        { 
                     Mage::log($e);
                     $this->_redirectError(502);
                    }
        $data['image'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
              } 
     else 
      {        
        if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1)
         $data['image'] = '';
        else 
        unset($data['image']);
      }
        $imageModel=Mage::getModel('blog/image');

                if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0 )
                  $articleModel->setCreatedTime(
                  Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                        ->gmtDate());
                  $articleModel
                  ->addData($postData)
                  ->setUpdatedTime(
                         Mage::getSingleton('core/date')
                         ->gmtDate())
                  ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                  ->save();
          $lastid = $articleModel->getId();
        $imageModel->setArticleId($lastid)->setImage($data['image'])->save();
          foreach($postData['category_id'] as $cat_id)
        {
         $categoryModel = Mage::getModel('blog/category');
         if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') <= 0 )
                     $categoryModel->setCategoryId($cat_id)->setArticleId($lastid)->save();
             $categoryModel->setCategoryId($cat_id)->setArticleId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->save();
        }
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                           ->addSuccess('successfully saved');
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                            ->setarticleData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;

          } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                              ->addError($e->getMessage());
             Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                ->setarticleData($this->getRequest()
                                ->getPost());
             $this->_redirect('*/*/edit',
                        array('id' => $this->getRequest()
                                            ->getParam('id')));
             return;
            }
          }
          $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
      public function deleteAction()
      {
          if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0)
          {  $articleId=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            try
            {
                $articleModel = Mage::getModel('blog/article');
                $articleModel->setId($this->getRequest()
                             ->getParam('id'))
                             ->delete();
        $categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', array('eq'=>$articleId));
        foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
            $cat->delete(); }

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                           ->addSuccess('successfully deleted');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
             }
             catch (Exception $e)
              {
                       Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                            ->addError($e->getMessage());
                       $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
              }
         }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
       }

public function massDeleteAction()
{
$catIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if (!is_array($catIds)) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select item(s)'));
} else {
try {
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
$cat = Mage::getModel('blog/article')->load($catId);
$cat->delete();
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', array('eq'=>$catId));
    foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
    $cat->delete();
        }
}
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted',
count($catIds))
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

public function massActiveAction()
{
$catIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if (!is_array($catIds)) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
} else {
try {
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
Mage::getSingleton('blog/article')
->load($catId)
->setStatus('Active')
->setIsMassupdate(true)
->save();
}
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
$this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($catIds))
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}

public function massInactiveAction()
{
$catIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if (!is_array($catIds)) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
} else {
try {
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
Mage::getSingleton('blog/article')
->load($catId)
->setStatus('Inactive')
->setIsMassupdate(true)
->save();
}
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
$this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($catIds))
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
}
?>
```

I tried changing the path form `media` to `media/newfolder` but whenever I tried to do something like this it shows an error.
How can I change the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this before calling `$uploader->save`

```
$uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
```

This will create the folder if it does not exist.
Then you can change your destination folder like this:

```
$media_path  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS. 'newfolder' . DS;
```

Comment: it is showing the same error this time also. the error is """Fatal error: Call to undefined method Vertax_Blog_Adminhtml_ArticleController::redirectError() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/app/code/local/Vertax/Blog/controllers/Adminhtml/ArticleController.php on line 112""" and the line is the `catch` section of the save action

Comment: @waseem. Maybe you should post your full controller. I don't think this has something to do with the image upload.  I think you are calling a method `redirectError` that should be `_redirectError`. `redirectError` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for that, now the error is gone but still the image is not saved in the newfolder. I am posting my controller in the question.

Comment: have you seen anything what is happening wrong over here

Comment: @waseem. It looks ok to me at a first glance. I see that you log the exception when uploading the file. Check `var/log` for more details. It should give you an idea of what's happening.

Comment: everything is good except that the folder dont have the permission to write. thanks

Comment: How Do I done this in magento 2